# com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ResourceExtractor.getOutputDirFromContext(ResourceExtractor.java:307)

Tags: android, webview

I am getting a strange error in android 4.4, this seems to be in webview, anybody have any idea to fix the bug, since the crash looks native, and i am not able figure out which class has the crash, so that i can handle the exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ResourceExtractor.getOutputDirFromContext(ResourceExtractor.java:307)
    at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ResourceExtractor.<init>(ResourceExtractor.java:266)
    at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ResourceExtractor.get(ResourceExtractor.java:232)
    at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.BrowserStartupController.prepareToStartBrowserProcess(BrowserStartupController.java:266)
    at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.BrowserStartupController.startBrowserProcessesSync(BrowserStartupController.java:186)
    at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwBrowserProcess$1.run(AwBrowserProcess.java:49)
    at com.android.org.chromium.base.ThreadUtils.runOnUiThreadBlocking(ThreadUtils.java:64)
    at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwBrowserProcess.start(AwBrowserProcess.java:45)
    at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.startChromiumLocked(WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.java:185)
    at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.access$100(WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.java:58)
    at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider$1.run(WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.java:123)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: did you find the problem?
I have the same problem for just create new Webview and my app is crashing..

Comment: This might be related. https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/content/public/android/java/src/org/chromium/content/browser/ResourceExtractor.java?view=log&pathrev=158801